# Get Realm value when using List<> values

Tags: swift, realm

How do you get the value of the Realm record when referencing a list?

I set up the Model with this:

```
class Entry: Object{
   var action = List<ContractAction>()
```

which is a reference to this

```
class ContractAction: Object{

@objc dynamic public private(set) var id = ""
@objc dynamic var action:String = ""
var parentCategoty = LinkingObjects(fromType: Entry.self, property: "action")
```

Here is a printout of the realm record.

```
Optional(Entry {
id = 1;
title = First Entry;
action = List<ContractAction> <0x6000039ce2e0> (
    [0] ContractAction {
        id = 1;
        action = Buy & Sell;
    }
   );
date = 2018-11-24 05:52:14 +0000;
})
```

If I print(Entry.action) I get this.

```
Optional(List<ContractAction> <0x600000d46490> (
[0] ContractAction {
    id = 1;
    action = Buy & Sell;
  }
))
```

How do I get the ContractAction ID of "1" or the action of "Buy & Sell" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Realm `List` is a collection, so you can access its items via subscript:

```
let actionId = anEntry.action[0].id
```

You can also use `first` to access the first action of an entry object:

```
let actionId = anEntry.action.first?.id
```